# Asp.net MVC3 intellisense in view HTML attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is annoying and was something I hoped they would fix for MVC3

just started a fresh MVC3 project and still I dont get intellisense from a view when in an HTML attribue

so with this example below I dont get intellisense.

```
<img src="/VehicleImages/<%=Model.AdvertVehicle.SapCode%>.jpg" />
```

I would have to copy and paste it outside the attribue and then I get intellisense.

Is there a setting when I can turn this on ??

Truegilly

Comment: You should have intellisense with HTML and attributes. Do you have intellisense in normal *.html files? Perhaps you need to reinstall ASP.NET MVC 3? What do you mean exactly with 'I would have to copy and paste '?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree this is incredibly annoying. I was hoping they'd fix it in VS2010 but it didn't happen.

This is the sole reason I bought ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not supported. Hope they will fix it in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

It IS Supported. Use Razor View Engine. Personally i would use razor if it had not got Intellisense at all

Comment: can you suggest any advantages Razor offers over the aspx engine?

Comment: Lots and lots. But Less code is the first advantage. Razor also does not need code end markers. See [Scot Guthrie's post about Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx). I'm sure you will see the advantages at the first sight